# Is there a way to parse PHP from a file that has been loaded by PHP code?

Tags: php, html

I am loading HTML/PHP code from an external textfile with

```
$f = fopen($filename, "r");
while ($line = fgets($f, 4096)) 
{
  print $line;
}
```

Is there a way to have the server parse the PHP code that is in this file? I am currently only using a simple `<?php echo("test"); ?>` in the external file (held in `$filename`) to test if it works. I tried using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` in the main file, but to no avail. I am open to other solutions, but if possible, I'd like to maintain the separation of the files and use only PHP to ease future upgrades to the website.

Comment: what's wrong with include or require ?

Comment: Yes you can: [eval($line);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: define "external" - from another URL, or from the file system?

Comment: @RemcoOverdijk Rasmus Lerdorf, the creator of PHP once said "If eval() is the answer, you’re almost certainly asking the wrong question." This applies nicely in this situation.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder And I fully agree! So I posted it as a comment, not as an answer; It is a direct answer to his question, but in no-way an answer to the problem. (I did however forget to add "But Don't." to my previous comment)

Comment: @Alnitak external means a different file in the same folder on the server. My ultimate goal is that I create a (small, if that is of any consequence) site that has its header and menu items in one file (so that all pages share the same menu), and for the same reason, a common right-side bar with ads and a footer in another, and only load content in the middle pane depending on the menu item selected. If anyone posts a link to a better solution, as I'm sure there are such, I'd be really happy and grateful. I'm awfully new to PHP btw, so please be kind :)

Comment: @bladerunner1992 sounds like a perfect case for `include`, then!

Comment: @Alnitak, @Benjamin Gruenbaum, `include` worked like a charm, thanks a lot :). I knew I was doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are looking for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

But please take the warning to heart:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

If anything, try to find a different sollution maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents($link)` to get the output of the file.

Check [PHP Manual for file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what you need.

If you are using it in a template type of scenario, ie, want to display data to a PHP file and echo the results use ob_start and get_clean to catch the output and store the results in a variabe:

```
ob_start();
eval('?>'.file_get_contents($file).'<?');
$result = ob_get_clean();

echo $result;
```

Otherwise, a simple:

```
eval('?>'.file_get_contents($file).'<?');
```

Will work.

**Note**: eval() should always be used sparingly and if possible, not at all for security and performance concerns.